# How to add a sub-theme for mobile version?

Tags: 7, theming

I finished my drupal site, and now I should create the mobile version.First I'm using [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) 3.3.5 with a sub-theme, and drupal 7. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain it but I want like, add a another sub-theme  like my existing sub-theme and change on it for mobile with saving all my node and views, thank you.

Comment: The idea of using Bootstrap is that your site is responsive.. Is that not happening? Or do you want different content?

Comment: Do you have some specific purpose of creating sub-theme? IF not you can apply any specific change to mobile version using CSS with that sub-theme itself.

Comment: Most often this is done with media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in the existing theme. And I agree with the others: Bootstrap uses media queries itself and is designed to work on multiple devices.

Comment: thank you guys for responding, yes bootstrap is responsive , and i want to add another subtheme just to delete some contents and change others in mobile version , wich i switch to it by the module mobile theme

Comment: Hey @Aymen : All the advice above is good, stick to it. Try to update your question to better describe your reqs or goals. Then you can get better answers. For example; "I want to hide a specific block from the mobile version" would be a clear requirement. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Create another subtheme (lets call it `mobiletheme` ) and with [mobile theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_theme) module set your mobile version of site use `mobiletheme`.

> Adds the ability to choose a mobile theme in
>   admin/build/themes/settings which is used for serving users on mobile
>   devices.

another solution is detect and set theme for mobile with [themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module (Check  tutorial here: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode52 )

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's
>   theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> ```
> individually-styled channels
> a front-page / "splash" screen
> a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> content, user, or role -specific themes
> indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> testing your redesign safely on a live server
> ...
> ```
>
> And unlike other theme switching modules, ThemeKey should play well
>   with internal and external page caches, like Boost or Varnish, even
>   for anonymous users.

**but really it is heavy module and if you want only want switch to another theme when user surf site with mobile I strongly recommend you to use   mobile theme module.**

Comment: thank you for responding,i want to keep my current subtheme with contents, and just delete some contents and change some others , that's way i want to create another subtheme and change on it ,and define it for mobile by the module mobile theme , thank you

Comment: @Aymen you're welcome, just duplicate current theme,  do your changes on it and use it as mobile.where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another theme to your site and setup the mobile devices indicator in the themekey][1](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. Themekeys supports:

- mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices